# Compiling Simple MongoDB + Java Example

Tags: java, mongodb

I seem to be unable to compile a simple MongoDB + Java Example:

I have this file
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/examples/QuickTour.java

In my command line I compile by doing

$ javac -cp mongo-2.10.1.jar QuickTour.java
$ java -cp mongo-2.10.1.jar QuickTour

However it gives me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: QuickTour
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QuickTour
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

What is going on and how can I fix this? Is it something to do with my compilation arguments?

Thanks...

Comment: The error does not seem related to mongo at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the compile time error. It's the error you got when you try to run your `class`. And the error simply says that it cannot find the class that you are trying to run. That error almost always means that you messed up with the classpath.

The problem is, you forgot to include the current directory in your argument to `classpath`. Add a `dot(.)` in addition to your `mongo.jar` file as the argument to `-cp`:

```
java -cp .;mongo-2.10.1.jar QuickTour
```

This assuming that you are executing your `QuickTour` class from  the same directory where you have placed it.

Comment: hm, i tried that but java just prints the help screen for the java command. is it working for you?

Comment: What environment are you using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: In that case, use `:` as separator on classpath rather than `;`.

Comment: `java -cp .:mongo-2.10.1.jar QuickTour`